# Android Permission interaction issue on system app on android 8

Tags: android, shell, permissions, adb

I have created an android system app and the system does not have a screen to interact with it. Currently, it is asking for permission at the first time after installation open ex for location and storage and if I want to install any app using it / uninstall it will ask for permission again in it. I  want to give it all the permission using adb or in app without user interaction in it

```
permission: android.permission.INTERNET
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE'
permission: android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
permission: android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
permission: android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
permission: android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
permission: android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
uses-permission: name='android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES'
permission: android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES
permission: android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP
permission: android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
permission: android.permission.REBOOT
permission: android.permission.SHUTDOWN
permission: android.permission.DEVICE_POWER
permission: android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
permission: android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
```

i try to give permission using this commands but didn't succeed in it

`adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.INTERNET
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.REQUEST_DELETE_PACKAGES
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.REBOOT
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.SHUTDOWN
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.DEVICE_POWER
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS
adb shell pm grant com.xxx.remotemanagementservice android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`